# Locked out of AD B2C Settings due to the missing 2FA

Tags: active-directory, azure

As an admin, I have always had access to Azure AD B2C Settings by opening B2C tenant to create user flows, add new users, etc. I had to replace my cell phone and the I cannot access to the AD B2C settings due to the unavailable 2FA code on my new mobile phone. Now I am totally locked out and unable to access the AD B2C settings. There are no other admins but me to seek their help too. How can I restore my access to AD B2C Settings?

Comment: which Product has been involved to use the 2FA?its really not clear to me, how you could have only one access token.

Comment: Contact Microsoft. They have account recovery for paying customers.

Comment: @djdomi Azure AD B2C 2FA is the problem that I cannot overcome. The 2FA was working on the authentication app on the previous cell phone.

Comment: open up a Case on microsoft and mostly any Account has at least a phone number as a backup